# Run a task in background every X hours and listen events

Tags: android, android-service, android-jetpack, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

I'm trying to make an app that must listen to certain events occurring on the phone (such as SMS sending/receiving, screen locking/unlocking) and execute a task every day (it doesn't have to be a precise hour and can be executed when phone is inactive).

The problem is : 
- It must be the most invisible possible for the user (no notification if possible)
- Restart automatically when phone restarts
- And not stop when source application stops (when the user manually stop it)

I searched about Services, which seems to quit when I quit application (and... well it looks like it's deprecated) and I'm now trying to use WorkManager from Android Jetpack API (which still doesn't update anymore when I quit app, but I'm probably doing it wrong).

Anybody has some references I can read ? I'm a bit lost

Comment: You're probably looking for Device Admin API - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DeviceAdminService
More on Device aministration: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html